# Wrong bounding box size of text with MeasureText using NoPadding option

Tags: .net, vb.net, text, bounding-box, measurement

I need to get the real bounding box, where is no padding at all(from all directions). I need it for packing words into rectangle. Unfortunately it does not work like I want. I searched a lot on the internet. Thanks in advance

// EDIT

I figured out that with other overloaded function MeasureText where I send also e.Graphics, I get this nicer but not completely what I want.

So is there any way how to clamp it to barebone text rectangle? I have an idea about drawing it into bitmap and checking top colored pixel and so on and then make a rectangle, but it would be slow I think.

[image: the wrong bounding box]

```
e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias
Dim wordFont As New System.Drawing.Font("Times", 100, FontStyle.Regular)
'Here is the change, I send also e.Graphics
Dim recSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(e.Graphics, "THE", wordFont,
                                       New Size(Integer.MaxValue, Integer.MaxValue),
                                       TextFormatFlags.NoPadding)

e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, New Rectangle(0, sum, recSize.Width, recSize.Height))
TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "THE", wordFont, New Point(0, 0),
                                      Color.Black, TextFormatFlags.NoPadding)
```

Comment: You'll have to pinvoke GetTextExtentPoint32().

Comment: I have found this link http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/gettextextentpoint32.html , but I do not know how to get it working. Can you please help me with this? Thanks a lot